# which one is powerful .load or .ajax or .post jquery ....? which one is recomended to use

Tags: javascript, jquery

which one is powerful .load or .ajax or .post jquery ....? which one is recomended to use

Comment: They are all synonyms of the same function, so the differences are syntactical only. See @David's answer.

Answer (score 3):

> which one is powerful .load or .ajax or .post jquery ....?

Err. Either `.ajax` for it's flexibility or `.load` for doing more stuff.

"Power" is a worthless measure though.

> which one is recomended to use

That one that does the job you need it to do. If one size fit all then there would only be one method.

Comment: @wajid — if you *really* care, then you can go through the changelogs on the jQuery site to find out which was most recently introduced. That's an even less useful measure than "Power" though.

Comment: ok ............. i went through different resoruces ......... now yorus one is last and it recommends me kinda i shall use .load .... thanx

Comment: No. I do **not** recommend you use load (I don't recommend against it either). It does more stuff. It is less flexible. If it does what you need then it is probably a decent choice. I don't know what you need so I cannot make a recommendation.

Comment: yup it works for me ............

Answer (score 1):

`$.load` does technically do the same thing as `$.ajax` or `$.post` (but in actual fact, it does a `$.get` instead of posting data.

`$.load` performs a get on a script and returns the `responseText` from jQuery.com

> This method is the simplest way to fetch data from the server. It is roughly equivalent to $.get(url, data, success)

Check out http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/